# Why is my toast working with so many different contexts?

Tags: android

I'm working in my activity4.java and the code is:

```
public class Activity4 extends Activity {
Spinner spinner;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_4);
    spinner=findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if(Activity4.this==adapterView.getContext())
            Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(),adapterView.getSelectedItem().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

I used adapterView.getContext() as context in the above code. But even if I replace it with getApplicationContext() like

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),adapterView.getSelectedItem().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

or if I write getBaseContext() like this,

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),adapterView.getSelectedItem().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The toast seems to work just fine. Why is it so?

Comment: why would you do adapterView.getContext()? You would do MainActivity.this

Answer (score 0):

This is the implementation of the makeText() method in Toast.java:

```
/**
 * Make a standard toast that just contains a text view.
 *
 * @param context  The context to use.  Usually your {@link android.app.Application}
 *                 or {@link android.app.Activity} object.
 * @param text     The text to show.  Can be formatted text.
 * @param duration How long to display the message.  Either {@link #LENGTH_SHORT} or
 *                 {@link #LENGTH_LONG}
 *
 */
public static Toast makeText(Context context, CharSequence text, @Duration int duration) {
    return makeText(context, null, text, duration);
}
```

As you can see in the comments for `@param context` explains that it **usually** is the application's context or the activity's context.

But the documentation:

> This method takes three parameters: the application Context, the text
>   message, and the duration for the toast

states that the context must be the application Context.

Well it seems that Toast just needs a context.  
If possible we must use application Context to avoid unexpected results.  
Although I haven't seen any yet.

Comment: That's probably not the best overload to demonstrate since it only calls another form of makeText. In the actual implementation, it does "LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);". That's why it needs the context.to inflate "com.android.internal.R.layout.transient_notification"

Comment: @Elletlar maybe but it is the most used